# Bypass Carrierwave uploader when saving to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have the Carrierwave gem installed in my Rails 4 app. I've created an Event model where an image location is saved to the model using the uploader. This works fine for image upload.

This is my code in the model

    `attr_accessor :image
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`

Now I want to make new events without uploading another image. I just want to save the image location in the new event. But because the uploader is in place when I try to save just the image location in a new Event it doesn't save.

How do I bypass this uploader and just save the image location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update_column` method allowed me to directly change this in the database. And the square bracket notion allowed me to directly read the column without the Carrierwave object wrapper.

Like this:  `event.update_column(:image, original_event["image"])`

Answer (score 0):

wibberding's answer is good for relational DBs, but not Mongo. Since OP didn't specify one way or the other, this is the equivalent operation in Mongoid. It is atomic and performs no secret callbacks.

```
Event.collection.update_one({ _id: BSON::ObjectId('579aeeeeb1fb439efbddda17') }, { "$set" => { image: 'my new image name' } })
```

Mongoid docs say this should be equivalent, but it did not change the DB when I tried:

```
event.set(:image, 'my new image name')
```